# "undefined" in get of Object.defineProperty in Constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, get, set

I can not understand what I make wrong in way to display current values of firstName and lastName methods. For now I have an error in jone.Name and jone.last, because they get - undefined.

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function() {
        this.firstName = this.fullName[0];
        return this.firstName;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        this.lastName = this.fullName[1];
        return this.lastName;
    }   
  });

}

var jone= new User("Jone Coven");

console.log(jone.fullName);
console.log(jone.firstName);
console.log(jone.lastName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `this.firstName = ...` and `this.lastName = ...` override the properties that are already defined using `Object.defineProperty(this, ...)`.

Here's a fixed version that uses additional private properties `this._firstName` and `this._lastName`:

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function() {
        this._firstName = this.fullName[0]; // <------ _firstName
        return this._firstName;
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        this._lastName = this.fullName[1]; // <----- _lastName
        return this._lastName;
    }   
  });

}

var jone= new User("Jone Coven");

console.log(jone.fullName);
console.log(jone.firstName);
console.log(jone.lastName);
```

---

Another solution is to return the result right away:

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.fullName[0];
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.fullName[1];
    }   
  });

}

var jone= new User("Jone Coven");

console.log(jone.fullName);
console.log(jone.firstName);
console.log(jone.lastName);
```

---

Comment: The second solution is just what I need. Now I'm understand what I make wrong in defineProperty. Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 2):

Why complicate this?

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' ');
  this.firstName = this.fullName[0];
  this.lastName = this.fullName[1];
}

var jone= new User("Jone Coven");
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But in this case I must set propeties in constructor only by Object.defineProperty descriptor. :(

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that only makes sense if you use defineProperty to change some of the standard meta data like writable, configurable, etc. Or if your getters and setters do something more than just return a property, neither of which are shown in your code. So if you go for Dmitris second solution, cdoshis code is functionally identical.

Answer (score 0):

```
function User(fullName) {
  this.fullName = fullName.split(' '); 
 this.firstName = function() {
        return this.fullName[0];

    }
this.lastName = function() {
        return this.fullName[1];

    }
}

var jone= new User("Jone Coven");

console.log(jone.fullName);
console.log(jone.firstName());
console.log(jone.lastName());
```